# Database design - efficient text searching

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I have a table that contains URL strings, i.e.

```
/A/B/C
/C/E
/C/B/A/R
```

Each string is split into tokens where the separator in my case is '/'. Then I assign integer value to each token and the put them into dictionary (different database table) i.e.

```
A : 1
B : 2
C : 3
E : 4
D : 5
G : 6
R : 7
```

My problem is to find those rows in first tables which contain given sequence of tokens. Additional problem is that my input is sequence of ints, i.e. I have

```
3, 2
```

and I'd like to find following rows

```
/A/B/C
/C/B/A/R
```

How to do this in efficient way. By this I mean how to design proper database structure.

I use PostgreSQL, solution should work well for 2 mln of rows in first table.

To clarify my example - I need both 'B' AND 'C' to be in the URL. Also 'B' and 'C' can occur in any order in the URL.

I need efficient SELECT. INSERT does not have to be efficient. I do not have to do all work in SQL if this changes anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you add `ABC` and `DBAR`? Are you looking for records that have BOTH (`B` AND `C`) or any of them (`B` or `C`)? Note `ABC` have both and `DBAR` have one. However `CE` also has one and it isn't displayed in the result set :S

Comment: my mistake. I have corrected example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this, but I'm just giving you some idea that might be useful. You already have your initial table. You process is and create the token table:

```
+------------+---------+
| TokenValue | TokenId |
+------------+---------+
| A          |       1 |
| B          |       2 |
| C          |       3 |
| E          |       4 |
| D          |       5 |
| G          |       6 |
| R          |       7 |
+------------+---------+
```

That's ok for me. Now, what I would do is to create a new table in which I would match the original table with the tokens of the token table (`OrderedTokens`). Something like:

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| UrlID | TokenId | AnOrder |
+-------+---------+---------+
|     1 |       1 |       1 |
|     1 |       2 |       2 |
|     1 |       3 |       3 |
|     2 |       5 |       1 |
|     2 |       2 |       2 |
|     2 |       1 |       3 |
|     2 |       7 |       4 |
|     3 |       3 |       1 |
|     3 |       4 |       2 |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

This way you can even recreate your original table as long as you use the order field. For example:

```
select string_agg(t.tokenValue, '/' order by ot.anOrder) as OriginalUrl
from OrderedTokens as ot
join tokens t on t.tokenId = ot.tokenId
group by ot.urlId
```

The previous query would result in:

```
+-------------+
| OriginalUrl |
+-------------+
| A/B/C       |
| D/B/A/R     |
| C/E         |
+-------------+
```

So, you don't even need your original table anymore. If you want to get Urls that have any of the provided token ids (in this case `B` OR `C`), you sould use this:

```
select string_agg(t.tokenValue, '/' order by ot.anOrder) as OriginalUrl
from OrderedTokens as ot
join Tokens t on t.tokenId = ot.tokenId
group by urlid
having count(case when ot.tokenId in (2, 3) then 1 end) > 0
```

This results in:

```
+-------------+
| OriginalUrl |
+-------------+
| A/B/C       | => It has both B and C
| D/B/A/R     | => It has only B
| C/E         | => It has only C
+-------------+
```

Now, if you want to get all Urls that have BOTH ids, then try this:

```
select string_agg(t.tokenValue, '/' order by ot.anOrder) as OriginalUrl
from OrderedTokens as ot
join Tokens t on t.tokenId = ot.tokenId
group by urlid
having count(distinct case when ot.tokenId in (2, 3) then ot.tokenId end) = 2
```

Add in the `count` all the ids you want to filter and then equal that count the the amount of ids you added. The previous query will result in:

```
+-------------+
| OriginalUrl |
+-------------+
| A/B/C       | => It has both B and C
+-------------+
```

The funny thing is that none of the solutions I provided results in your expected result. So, have I misunderstood your requirements or is the expected result you provided wrong?

Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: yes, your second solution is what I need. Now I have to check query performance. I also wonder if I can transform this SQL into django ORM.

Comment: Thanks, I slightly changed solution but the idea is the same. I used Django ORM and last query can be simply mapped into object by using raw query.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you mean by efficient.  It will be a trade-off between query performance and storage.

If you want to efficiently store this information, then your current approach is appropriate.  You can query the data by doing something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.url
FROM
  urls u
INNER JOIN
  dictionary d
ON
  d.id IN (3, 2)
  AND u.url ~ E'\\m' || d.url_component || E'\\m'
```

This query will take some time, as it will be required to do a full table scan, and perform regex logic on each URL.  It is, however, very easy to insert and store data.

If you want to optimize for query performance, though, you can create a reference table of the URL components; it would look something like this:

```
/A/B/C    A
/A/B/C    B
/A/B/C    C
/C/E      C
/C/E      E
/D/B/A/R  D
/D/B/A/R  B
/D/B/A/R  A
/D/B/A/R  R
```

You can then create a clustered index on this table, on the URL component.  This query would retrieve your results very quickly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.full_url
FROM
  url_components u
INNER JOIN
  dictionary d
ON
  d.id IN (3, 2)
  AND u.url_component = d.url_component
```

Basically, this approach moves the complexity of the query up front.  If you are doing few inserts, but lots of queries against this data, then that is appropriate.

Creating this URL component table is trivial, depending on what tools you have at your disposal.  A simple awk script could work through your 2M records in a minute or two, and the subsequent copy back into the database would be quick as well.  If you need to support real-time updates to this table, I would recommend a non-SQL solution: whatever your app is coded in could use regular expressions to parse the URL and insert the components into the component table.  If you are limited to using the database, then an insert trigger could fulfill the same role, but it will be a more brittle approach.

Comment: the problem with your second solution (best query performance is my priority) is that your SQL will return also '/B' or '/B/E/F' as well as expected '/B/C'

Comment: really sory, my example had a mistake :( I need that all tokens are present in result